# How to add a widget to a qt Tool bar

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following problem:
I have added a spinner to my qt Tool Bar, which is located from top to buttom. This works fine. But now I want to order some buttons in a special order, but with mainToolBar->addWidget(button_name) it would be among one other. So how can I solve it? I tried to make a new widget "widget_1" and added some buttons to this widget, but when I write mainToolBar->addWidget(widget_1) nothing appears, only the one slider I have already added. Can anyone help me?
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: `QToolBar::insertWidget(QAction* before, QWidget* widget)` will allow you to insert the widgets in an arbitrary order.  But that doesn't explain why adding your aggregate widget didn't work, for that you will have to post code.

Comment: hi! Sorry I was on vacation. I have created a widget with buttons and labels in it. when I execute the program there is the widget with all the buttons and labels in it, but if I write: mainToolBar->addWidget(widget) then the toolbar is empty and the widget disappears. What is QAction* before? What should I write there?

Comment: btw: the following code is part of the creation of the widget:  widget = new QWidget(centralWidget1);
        widget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("widget"));
        widget->setGeometry(QRect(520, 10, 161, 541));
        label_2 = new QLabel(widget);

Answer (score 0):

Well, just forget something.
select the widget and then layout in a form or whatever layouting you prefer.
And that's it. now, the widget will be shown in toolbar. it's because of size
and child widgets position. by layouting, everything will be resized and position
correctly.